# R parse list and populate data.table optimization

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following R code. It creates a list 'data_list' with 1600 elements. Each element is a list with 2 elements: 'sample' and 'input'. An output data.table 'out_dt' is created and populated with the means and sd of the values present in 'input'.

```
library(data.table)

# create an example data list with 1600 elements
# create the input data_list
set.seed(123)

n_samples <- 1600
n_regions_at_start <- 50000
chr_sample_at_start <- sample(1:22, n_regions_at_start, replace = TRUE)
start_sample_at_start <- sort(sample(1:100000, n_regions_at_start))
end_sample_at_start <- sort(sample(100001:200000, n_regions_at_start))

data_list <- vector("list", n_samples)

for (i in 1:n_samples) {
  # use this trick to create input_dfs with a varying number of rows. This is an extra complexity compared to the first code
  if (i %% 5 == 0) {
    elements_to_remove = sort(sample(1:n_regions_at_start, 5))
    n_regions <- n_regions_at_start - 5
    CHR <- chr_sample_at_start[-c(elements_to_remove)]
    START <- start_sample_at_start[-c(elements_to_remove)]
    END <- end_sample_at_start[-c(elements_to_remove)]
  } else {
    n_regions <- n_regions_at_start
    CHR <- chr_sample_at_start
    START <- start_sample_at_start
    END <- end_sample_at_start
  }
  
  sample_list <- list(sample = paste0("Sample", i))
  
  input_df <- data.frame (
    CHR = CHR,
    START = START,
    END = END,
    COL1 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL2 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL3 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL4 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL5 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL6 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL7 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL8 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL9 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL10 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL11 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL12 = rnorm(n_regions),
    COL13 = rnorm(n_regions)
  )
  data_list[[i]] <- list(sample = sample_list$sample, input = input_df)
}

# get the data for the first 3 columns of out_dt
region_concat_list <- lapply(data_list, function(x) paste(x$input[["CHR"]], x$input[["START"]], x$input[["END"]], sep = "-"))
region_vec_all_unique <- unique(unlist(region_concat_list))

# create the output data.table with first 3 columns
out_dt <- data.table("CHR" = sapply(region_vec_all_unique, function(x) as.character(unlist(strsplit(x, "-"))[1])), "START" = as.numeric(sapply(region_vec_all_unique, function(x) as.character(unlist(strsplit(x, "-"))[2]))), "END" = as.numeric(sapply(region_vec_all_unique, function(x) as.character(unlist(strsplit(x, "-"))[3]))))

# Get column names for means and sds
colnames_mean <- paste0(names(data_list[[1]]$input)[4:16], ".MEAN")
colnames_sd <- paste0(names(data_list[[1]]$input)[4:16], ".SD")

# Calculate means and sds and add them to out_dt
print(Sys.time())
for (i in seq_len(nrow(out_dt))) {
  print(paste("row", i, Sys.time()))
  chr_val <- as.numeric(unname(unlist(out_dt[i, "CHR"])))
  start_val <- as.numeric(unname(unlist(out_dt[i, "START"])))
  end_val <- as.numeric(unname(unlist(out_dt[i, "END"])))
  for (j in 4:16) {
    out_dt[i, colnames_mean[j-3] := mean(unlist(sapply(data_list, function(x) x$input[x$input$CHR == chr_val & x$input$START == start_val & x$input$END == end_val, j])), na.rm = TRUE)]
    out_dt[i, colnames_sd[j-3] :=  sd(unlist(sapply(data_list, function(x) x$input[x$input$CHR == chr_val & x$input$START == start_val & x$input$END == end_val, j])), na.rm = TRUE)]
  }
}
print(Sys.time())
```

I would like help with

- optimizing this code in terms of speed given the number of elements (1600) and the number of rows (50000). Currently, on my machine it takes 15s for each iteration of i. So this means that it will take 208h to finish. I'm aware of parallelization and I would be interested in some solutions using that approach, however I would also like to know if without using parallelization the code can still be optimized?

Comment: Hard to read your code, could you explain what you are trying to do? Are we trying to get mean and sd for each COL1, COL2... per sample, i.e. take mean of COL1 at row1 from each sample?

Comment: Hi @user1987607! The (full) data in your post is indeed nice for timing. But can you please add a minimal example as well, just for people to try out the logic? Perhaps two list elements, with data frames with e.g. five rows and two "COL" columns, together with desired output? Cheers

Comment: @zx8754: I've edited the code using your suggestions and added the extra complexity which you made me aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dcast(
  melt(
    rbindlist(lapply(data_list, "[[", "input_df")),
    measure = patterns("^COL")
  )[, .(SD = sd(value), MEAN = mean(value)), .(CHR, START, END, variable)], 
  CHR + START + END ~ variable, value.var = c("MEAN", "SD")
)
```

**note** using the same data as provided by @zx8754

**result**

```
      CHR  START     END MEAN_COL1  MEAN_COL2  MEAN_COL3 SD_COL1 SD_COL2 SD_COL3
   1:   1  33714 1047782  0.141747  0.2738446  0.1534639 0.79823 0.92176 0.59589
   2:   1 130552 1120116  0.373040 -0.2715679  0.0181300 1.19567 0.80810 1.06344
   3:   1 159027 1154071 -0.150262 -0.0466695  0.0029242 0.91435 0.92095 0.95829
   4:   1 167912 1173695  0.141090 -0.3735618 -0.4127391 1.00912 1.05998 0.75489
   5:   1 190046 1190635 -0.223469 -0.1353540 -0.5677172 1.16733 1.23969 0.99495
  ---                                                                           
 996:  22 920450 1933075  0.046370  0.1025626 -0.3027420 1.03382 1.27190 0.94798
 997:  22 947212 1957620  0.247132  0.0573555 -0.3610278 1.10706 1.01420 1.15222
 998:  22 959074 1963730  0.237973  0.0089281 -0.1306382 0.78475 0.70369 0.86592
 999:  22 959963 1964285 -0.496522  0.4612102 -0.1540762 1.19330 0.93966 0.87134
1000:  22 964800 1965878 -0.055107  0.0729134 -0.0650617 1.23578 0.77902 0.58955
```

Comment: 'zx8754' made me aware of some extra complexity in my code. I have edited my original post. I don't think the answer you provided will produce the desired results now. The code in my post works, but is taking way too long, so I'm really looking for speed optimization.

Comment: using dcast and melt did the trick indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the input example data is wrong, assuming you wanted to keep `"CHR, START, END"` same for all samples, try below example data/code:

```
#fixed example input
set.seed(123)
n = 1000
nSample = 10
data_list <- vector("list", nSample)
CHR = sample(1:22, n, replace = TRUE)
START = sort(sample(1:1000000, n))
END = sort(sample(1000001:2000000, n))

data_list <- lapply(seq_len(nSample), function(i)
  list(sample = paste0("Sample", i),
       input_df = data.frame(CHR = CHR,
                             START = START,
                             END = END,
                             COL1 = rnorm(n),
                             COL2 = rnorm(n),
                             COL3 = rnorm(n))))
```

Row bind all dataframes and get  *mean* and *sd* per group - `"CHR, START, END"`:

```
# rowbind all sample dataframes into one
d <- rbindlist(lapply(data_list, "[[", "input_df"))

cols <- grep("^COL", colnames(d), value = TRUE)
c_mean <- paste0(cols, ".MEAN")
c_sd <- paste0(cols, ".SD")

xMean <- d[, setNames(lapply(.SD, mean), c_mean),
           by = .(CHR, START, END), .SDcols = cols ]
xSd <- d[, setNames(lapply(.SD, sd), c_sd), 
         by = .(CHR, START, END), .SDcols = cols ]

merge(xMean, xSd)
#      CHR  START     END   COL1.MEAN    COL2.MEAN    COL3.MEAN   COL1.SD   COL2.SD   COL3.SD
#   1:   1  33714 1047782  0.14174709  0.273844573  0.153463929 0.7982275 0.9217612 0.5958855
#   2:   1 130552 1120116  0.37304042 -0.271567922  0.018130040 1.1956657 0.8081005 1.0634375
#   3:   1 159027 1154071 -0.15026192 -0.046669467  0.002924184 0.9143549 0.9209461 0.9582876
#   4:   1 167912 1173695  0.14108994 -0.373561765 -0.412739058 1.0091226 1.0599815 0.7548897
#   5:   1 190046 1190635 -0.22346940 -0.135353994 -0.567717226 1.1673282 1.2396899 0.9949541
#  ---                                                                                       
# 996:  22 920450 1933075  0.04637029  0.102562565 -0.302742004 1.0338246 1.2719033 0.9479758
# 997:  22 947212 1957620  0.24713213  0.057355540 -0.361027835 1.1070560 1.0142035 1.1522213
# 998:  22 959074 1963730  0.23797259  0.008928114 -0.130638235 0.7847488 0.7036875 0.8659236
# 999:  22 959963 1964285 -0.49652239  0.461210170 -0.154076189 1.1932974 0.9396573 0.8713406
#1000:  22 964800 1965878 -0.05510684  0.072913408 -0.065061699 1.2357829 0.7790229 0.5895477
```

Comment: You saying that the input data was not right, made me realize that there's indeed extra complexity that I didn't account for in my test code. The input_df don't necessarily have the same amount of rows. I'll change my initial post to take that into account.